TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unsubscribe') with react hook form and React latest version in RTL test cases
We have recently upgraded our react app to use react-18.3.1 version along with the react-hook-form latest =7.54.1, but while running test cases we started getting below error:

      42 |                      setSomeState(newValue); // changed to dummy for now
      43 |              })
    > 44 |              return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
         |                                        ^
      45 |      }, [watch])
      46 |      return {
      47 |              nameCount,

      at unsubscribe (src/pages/TestFileName.tsx:44:29)
      at safelyCallDestroy (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3922:844)
      at commitHookEffectListUnmount (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:3929:331)
      at commitPassiveUnmountInsideDeletedTreeOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4161:525)
      at commitPassiveUnmountEffectsInsideOfDeletedTree_begin (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4156:24)
      at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4143:2054)
      at commitPassiveUnmountEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4143:1714)
      at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4640:360)
      at flushPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4635:371)
      at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4625:82)
      at commitRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4549:209)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4444:97)
      at flushSyncCallbacks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:2155:108)
      at flushSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4457:66)
      at ReactDOMRoot.Object.<anonymous>.ReactDOMHydrationRoot.unmount.ReactDOMRoot.unmount [as unmount] (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:4917:1902)
      at Object.unmount (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:178:12)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:309:12
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:71:24
      at act (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2194:20)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:70:25
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:308:28
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:70:25
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:308:28
      at node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:308:28
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at cleanup (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:304:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/TestFileName.test.tsx:78:10)

Sample Code Snippet in our TestFileName.tsx:
const [nameCount, setNameCount] = useState(someStateData?.name?.length || 0)

useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = watch((value) => {
            setNameCount(value.name.length);
        })
        return () => subscription.unsubscribe(); // line where it is failing in test
    }, [watch])
    return {
        nameCount
    }
}

TestFileName is called from ParentContainer component as mentioned below and react hook form methods are passed to
ParentContainer.tsx

const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,....// other methods
    } = useForm({
        defaultValues: {
            firstName: someDefaultValue,
        },... // other attributes
});

return (
    <>
        <TestFileName
            register={register}
            watch={watch}
            setValue={setValue}
            setFocus={setFocus} />
    </>
)

In the test case we have initialized default props like below and passed in the test case:
const defaultProps = {
    register: jest.fn(),
    watch: jest.fn(),
    setError: jest.fn()
};

PS: Can anyone please guide what could be missing, why are we getting this error?

This error implies that subscription is potentially null | undefined, so attempting to access unsubscribe is failing.
Where does watch come from and what do you expect the type to be?

From react-hook-form watch docs

When defaultValue is not defined, the first render of watch will return undefined because it is called before register. It's recommended to provide defaultValues at useForm to avoid this behaviour, but you can set the inline defaultValue as the second argument.

Are you providing a defaultValues object to your useForm declaration?
const {watch} = useForm({defaultValues})


Hello Derek, yes we have initialized defaultValues in ParentContainer component and passed on all the react hook form methods to child component i.e. TestFileName. I have updated the other details as well in question where test case is failing.
